# Assign tabindex value in <a> tag and the value changes when the banner swipes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, swiper.js

I am trying to make the current banner's link can be accessed by keyboard (tabinex = 0) and the rest banner's link will not accessed by keyboard (tabindex = -1) so the screen reader only reads the current banner. When swipes the banner, the tabindex value will change.

In the javascript, I use `.hasClass` to find the relevant elements and then use `.attr` to assign the tabindex value. Here is the code:

```
    if ($("div").hasClass("swiper-slide") && $("div").hasClass("swiper-slide-active")) {
         $('div.swiperWrap > div > div > .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active > .caption > .hd > a').attr('tabindex','0');                                                                                                        
     }

     if ($("div").hasClass("swiper-slide") && $("div").hasClass("swiper-slide-duplicate-prev")) {                                                                                                    
        $('div.swiperWrap > div > div > .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-duplicate-prev > .caption > .hd > a').attr('tabindex','-1');
     }

     if ($("div").hasClass("swiper-slide") && $("div").hasClass("swiper-slide-duplicate-active")) {                                                                  
         $('div.swiperWrap > div > div > .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-duplicate-active > .caption > .hd > a').attr('tabindex','-1');
     } 
     
      if ($("div").hasClass("swiper-slide") && $("div").hasClass("swiper-slide-next")) {                                                                                              
         $('div.swiperWrap > div > div >  .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-next > .caption > .hd > a').attr('tabindex','-1');
     } 
     
      if ($("div").hasClass("swiper-slide") && $("div").hasClass("swiper-slide-prev")) {
         $('div.swiperWrap > div > div > .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-prev > .caption > .hd > a').attr('tabindex','-1');                                                                               
     }
```

Although the code above can put the tabindex in the  tag, I notice when the banner swipes, the tabindex value does not change  (I mean tabindex does not change from 0 to -1 and from -1 to 0). Please find the html code for review.

```
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active" data-swiper-slide-index="1" style="width: 412px; transition-duration: 0ms; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(-824px, 0px, 0px);">
                <div class="imgWrap">
                  <div class="img">
                    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1300 720" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
                      <defs>
                        <mask id="mask3">
                          <path fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd" class="st0" d="M42.9,285c32.6,236.7,249.2,412.1,483.7,391.7l773.4-67.2V0H104.8C52.7,80,28.4,179.7,42.9,285z"></path>
                        </mask>
                      </defs>
                      <image xlink:href="/folder/banner/en/1/1_main-banner-02.jpg" alt="Banner" mask="url(#mask3)" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                  <div class="hd">
                    <a tabindex="0" href="./mycompany/en/index3.html" target="_self">Banner Title
                    </a><!-- tabindex value does not change when banner swipes -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-next" data-swiper-slide-index="2" style="width: 412px; transition-duration: 0ms; opacity: 0; transform: translate3d(-1236px, 0px, 0px);">
                <div class="imgWrap">
                  <div class="img">
                    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1300 720" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
                      <defs>
                        <mask id="mask3">
                          <path fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd" class="st0" d="M42.9,285c32.6,236.7,249.2,412.1,483.7,391.7l773.4-67.2V0H104.8C52.7,80,28.4,179.7,42.9,285z"></path>
                        </mask>
                      </defs>
                      <image xlink:href="/folder/banner/en/1/139_main-banner-03.jpg" alt="Banner" mask="url(#mask3)" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                  <div class="hd">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="../mycompany/en/index2.html" target="_blank">Title here</a><!-- tabindex value does not change when banner swipes -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-prev" data-swiper-slide-index="0" style="width: 412px; transition-duration: 0ms; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(-412px, 0px, 0px);">
                <div class="imgWrap">
                  <div class="img">
                    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1300 720" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
                      <defs>
                        <mask id="mask3">
                          <path fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd" class="st0" d="M42.9,285c32.6,236.7,249.2,412.1,483.7,391.7l773.4-67.2V0H104.8C52.7,80,28.4,179.7,42.9,285z"></path>
                        </mask>
                      </defs>
                      <image xlink:href="/folder/banner/en/1/265_main-banner-02.jpg" alt="banner" mask="url(#mask3)" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                  <div class="hd">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="../mycompany/en/index2.html" target="_self">Banner Title
                    </a><!-- tabindex value does not change when banner swipes -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate swiper-slide-duplicate-prev" data-swiper-slide-index="0" style="width: 412px; transition-duration: 0ms; opacity: 0; transform: translate3d(-1648px, 0px, 0px);">
                <div class="imgWrap">
                  <div class="img">
                    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1300 720" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
                      <defs>
                        <mask id="mask3">
                          <path fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd" class="st0" d="M42.9,285c32.6,236.7,249.2,412.1,483.7,391.7l773.4-67.2V0H104.8C52.7,80,28.4,179.7,42.9,285z"></path>
                        </mask>
                      </defs>
                      <image xlink:href="/folder/banner/en/1/banner-02.jpg" alt="banner" mask="url(#mask3)" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                  <div class="hd">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="../mycompany/en/index1.html" target="_self">Banner Title
                    </a><!-- tabindex value does not change when banner swipes -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

I don't understand why the tabindex value does not change. Grateful if someone can give advice and let me know my mistakes please. Thank you very much.

Reference links:

[hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

[attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

[tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

[Keyboard Accessibility](https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex)